# How to Connect BizTalk to CRM Online 2015 Rest Endpoint Using ADFS

Tags: biztalk, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015, biztalk-2013

I'm attempting to connect to CRM 2015 Online Rest endpoint.  Is this even possible?  If so, what are the steps required to be able to connect?

Comment: That is rather a broad question. Yes it is possible to connect to Dynamics CRM Online .  e.g. http://www.neudesic.com/blog/biztalk-server-dynamics-crm-online-integration-premises-lines-business-systems-using-biztalk-server-2013/    There are also blogs around how to configure ADFS (not Dynamics CRM specific).

Comment: @Dijkgraaf the blog you list is exactly what we have followed, but we're authenticating against our local AD via ADFS, not using Windows Live Id, which is what the blog shows.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf oh, and the blog is for hitting the SOAP endpoint, not the OData

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new API preview: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm/webapipreview.aspx

As far is I know, the rest endpoint in CRM is not open for calls from outside of the CRM context. You can only call these endpoints from e.g. webresources.

Comment: The new WenAPI is not rest is it?

Comment: Quote from the page: This Web API Preview implements the OData (Open Data Protocol) v4. OData is an OASIS standard for building and consuming RESTful APIs over rich data sources.